# Problem of phishing magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, security, patches

I followed all the steps to solve the problem of phishing magento by timely updates not installed. Guruincsite.

I cleaned my database of foreign users, I cleaned the various tables listed in the guides, I cleaned logs, I pulled over code in the Magento administration panel. Yet after asking google reviews on the site keeps coming up with a poster of "Security Error".

Need help, thank you.

Comment: if you look through the code is there any code that's not yours? such as https://blog.sucuri.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/obfuscated-guruincsite-script.png have you also run your site through magereport.com

Comment: look for fake extensions and php backdoors in every folder

Answer (score 1):

1. You need find backdoor in your code, I recommend find something like "eval" keyword, you should remove it.
2. I recommend update your core version to 1.9.2.1.
3. I recommend set only read rights on source code files and folders. (except media and var)